# groupby and normalize over two arrays

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, group-by, multi-index

I have a`DataFrame` where the columns are a `MultiIndex`. The first `level` specifies `'labels'`, the second specifies `'values'`.  A `'label'` in the `(i, j)` position of `df.labels` corresponds to the `'value'` in the `(i, j)` position of `df.values`.

I want to rescale the `'values'` such that they sum to one within each group defined by the corresponding `'labels'`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
                                    (10, 5), p=(.4, .3, .2, .1)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame((np.random.rand(10, 5) * 10).round(0))

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=['labels', 'values'])
print df

  labels             values                     
       0  1  2  3  4      0    1     2    3    4
0      b  b  b  b  b    5.0  2.0   7.0  7.0  4.0
1      a  c  c  c  c    6.0  8.0   1.0  5.0  7.0
2      d  c  c  d  c    6.0  3.0  10.0  7.0  4.0
3      a  a  a  b  a    5.0  9.0   9.0  5.0  8.0
4      a  b  a  c  c    0.0  4.0   1.0  8.0  0.0
5      c  b  a  a  b    1.0  6.0   8.0  6.0  1.0
6      c  c  c  a  c    9.0  9.0   4.0  1.0  1.0
7      d  c  a  b  c    7.0  0.0   3.0  6.0  4.0
8      b  a  b  a  a    8.0  6.0   3.0  5.0  4.0
9      c  c  c  b  c    2.0  5.0   3.0  1.0  3.0
```

I expect the results to look like this:

```
  labels                values                                        
       0  1  2  3  4         0         1         2         3         4
0      b  b  b  b  b  0.084746  0.033898  0.118644  0.118644  0.067797
1      a  c  c  c  c  0.084507  0.091954  0.011494  0.057471  0.080460
2      d  c  c  d  c  0.300000  0.034483  0.114943  0.350000  0.045977
3      a  a  a  b  a  0.070423  0.126761  0.126761  0.084746  0.112676
4      a  b  a  c  c  0.000000  0.067797  0.014085  0.091954  0.000000
5      c  b  a  a  b  0.011494  0.101695  0.112676  0.084507  0.016949
6      c  c  c  a  c  0.103448  0.103448  0.045977  0.014085  0.011494
7      d  c  a  b  c  0.350000  0.000000  0.042254  0.101695  0.045977
8      b  a  b  a  a  0.135593  0.084507  0.050847  0.070423  0.056338
9      c  c  c  b  c  0.022989  0.057471  0.034483  0.016949  0.034483
```

Comment: Can clarify what is summing to 1 in your expected result?

Comment: @BrenBarn all values with a corresponding label of 'a' should sum to 1.

Comment: I see.  You have an answer below.  In general, though, I think operations like this are more straightforwardly handled if you reshape your data so that each row is a single observation.  For instance, one row would contain columns for "label", "number" (your 0-1-2-3-4), and "value".  It then becomes simple to group on any of these.

Comment: @BrenBarn I agree.  So this becomes an exercise in reshaping, grouping, and assigning.  I have my solution below (for those without privilege, it's deleted so you can't see it) which is how I generated the expected output.

Comment: Why did you delete your solution if it works?

Comment: @BrenBarn This get's into a meta topic.  In short, I'm going for the socratic badge.  I often come across clever solutions or interesting problems that don't get asked about.  I'm asking them so they get exposure.  I provided my answer, but I don't want it to discourage others from answering.  Nor do I want to bias their answers.  It is my intent to select the best answer (not mine) provided with in a time frame then undelete my answer.  This satisfies my urge to share my idea of possibly deeper questions to enrich the content on SO.  And it gets me closer to the socratic badge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the normalized values, you could:

```
new_values = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros(df['values'].shape))
for v in np.unique(df['labels']):
    mask = df['values'].where(df['labels'].isin([v]))
    new_values += mask.div(mask.sum().sum()).fillna(0)
df.loc[:, 'values'] = new_values.values
```

also as a somewhat unreadable oneliner:

```
df.loc[:, 'values'] = np.sum([df['values'].where(df['labels'].isin([v])).div(df['values'].where(df['labels'].isin([v])).sum().sum()).fillna(0).values for v in np.unique(df['labels'])], axis=0)
```

or, using `.groupby()`:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((df['labels'].values.reshape(-1, 1), df['values'].values.reshape(-1, 1))))
df.loc[:, 'values'] = tmp.groupby(0).transform(lambda x: x/x.sum()).values.reshape(df['values'].shape)
```

both result in:

```
  labels                values                                        
       0  1  2  3  4         0         1         2         3         4
0      b  b  b  b  b  0.084746  0.033898  0.118644  0.118644  0.067797
1      a  c  c  c  c  0.084507  0.091954  0.011494  0.057471  0.080460
2      d  c  c  d  c  0.300000  0.034483  0.114943  0.350000  0.045977
3      a  a  a  b  a  0.070423  0.126761  0.126761  0.084746  0.112676
4      a  b  a  c  c  0.000000  0.067797  0.014085  0.091954  0.000000
5      c  b  a  a  b  0.011494  0.101695  0.112676  0.084507  0.016949
6      c  c  c  a  c  0.103448  0.103448  0.045977  0.014085  0.011494
7      d  c  a  b  c  0.350000  0.000000  0.042254  0.101695  0.045977
8      b  a  b  a  a  0.135593  0.084507  0.050847  0.070423  0.056338
9      c  c  c  b  c  0.022989  0.057471  0.034483  0.016949  0.034483
```

Answer (score 1):

While [`pd.DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) makes it convenient to retrieve some slices:

```
df.xs('values', axis=1, level=0)
```

It unfortunately does not allow us to assign.  If we want to use [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), we need to be able to specify the row and column indices we want to assign to.

- Use `pd.IndexSlice` to slice a `pd.MultiIndex` by its different levels.  The following is a generic representation of accessing the `values` indices from the first level and without restrictions on the second level.

  ```
  pd.IndexSlice['values', :]
  ```
- When we combine this with `pd.DataFrame.loc`, we allow ourselves to assign to very specific slices of the `pd.DataFrame`.  The following retrieves and allows assignment to all rows without restriction and columns restricted to those whose first level equals `'values'`

  ```
  df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice['values', :]]
  ```
- In order to normalize across the values in `labels` section, I'm going to `stack()` `df` so that I unwind all `'labels'` into a single column that is aligned with `values`.  This is the `head()` of this stacking

  ```
  df.stack().head()

      labels    values
  0 0      b  0.084746
    1      b  0.033898
    2      b  0.118644
    3      b  0.118644
    4      b  0.067797
  ```
- At this point the `groupby('labels')` is pretty straight forward with the exception that I use `.values` at the end to avoid having to produce the correct indices when I know I've already got the array of values in the correct order.

---

***final answer***

```
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice['values', :]] = \
    df.stack().groupby('labels')['values'].apply(
        lambda x: x / x.sum()).unstack().values
```